Is this an appropriate parenthetical use, or should I use a colon or some other sentence construction?
In the sentence below, I believe that I need to use a colon after "puffs," but I really want to use a comma. So I would like to know if the below sentence is grammatically correct or not.

There is hope I can eat all these corn puffs, to put them all in my bowl, to pour milk over them, to crunch each and every one of them in my mouth, and finally, to swallow them down my throat.

PS: The above sentence is made up, to get to the principle of the matter, as the sentence that I am actually using is pretty complex. :^)
UPDATE FOLLOWS
In regard to sentence in question, the context for this type of sentence is a white paper, so one could consider the context to be academic or scholarly. However, the paper will probably be about 75 pages of almost entirely academic text. In the one-page section that I am using the above type of sentence, my intention is to give the reader both a succinct comprehension and the emotional impact of about 60 or so pages of previous academic material: a difficult thing for me to do.
After reviewing the comments to my original post here, perhaps the way to view the trailing infinitives in the sentence in question is as a series of parenthetical expressions, used to provide additional details and impact to the initial, main clause. I’m not sure if that use is valid, however, or just distracting as an inappropriate or excessive use of creative license.
I really appreciate the feedback.
SOLUTION

There is hope that I can eat all these corn puffs, that I can put them all in my bowl, that I can pour milk over them, that I can crunch each and every one of them in my mouth, and finally, that I can swallow them down my throat.

Yes, it was a silly example. But it did help me understand and solve the problem that I was having…
Thanks, especially to Mr. Ashworth!


Questions that come up while learning English are a better fit at English Language Learners. 2) Please edit to say more about what kind of context you're looking for. You "may" do just about anything you like with language; artistic license lets you write word strings that are not grammatical sentences if you want, but it wouldn't be appropriate in scholarly writing. Finally: the really weird thing here isn't the punctuation but the "to"-infinitives.


Have you tried searching the 1000 other questions about comma usage? You need to think about the relationship between the different elements: are you listing multiple stages of action, or are you providing a summary of an action and then listing the stages making up that action? What logical relationship do you want to express? That said, nobody's going to kill you for using a comma here even if it obscures the logical relationship: it'll just be marginally less readable.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
